# how to use a proxy using javascript

Tags: javascript

the problem is that when i want to get the response from the server then it gives `null`

```
//url of web service        
url="http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=12INR=?GBP"
var xmlHttp=new xmlHttpRequest();
//object of xml request
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
//get method
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
try{
        if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) 
            return;                                 
        alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        var result = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
        var jsonString = result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;        
        var result1 = jsonParse(jsonString); 
        alert(result1.rhs);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = innerHTML;
            }
    catch(e1){alert("erroe="+e1);}
};
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send(null); 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do an AJAX call to www.google.com unless your page is already being served from the www.google.com domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: then what thing i have to do in this case???please explain in detail or can u post any relevant example for that so i can get responce from server...

Comment: Blame the guys who created thh annoyng same origin policy, of course. :) Anyway, the best course of action would be to either search for an alternative calculator API (for example, google maps has a JSONP javascript API that doesn't use AJAx and goes arouf the SOP) or you could send that request to your own server instead, do whatever you want over there and then return the results.

Comment: that is not the solution of problem .I must have to use this web service any how using java script only ,not by jquery or anything else

Comment: @KushalpalSingh you're asking how to do something impossible, then complaining when someone suggests an alternative? That seems short-sighted. But anyway 2 things: 1) jQuery _is_ Javascript, and 2) you misspelled `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Dan thanx for response but till now i did't understand the problem,if i can't use this web service then what is the use of this web service. I can get responce when i call this using java.

Comment: Well, on further investigation, it appears that this particular Google API returns JSON, which means that you can call it from a `<script>`tag rather than an `XMLHttpRequest` and thus bypass the origin policy. This is essentially what @missingno was referring to, but he/she assumed as I did that you were planning to use XHR because that's the only way to call this particular API. It isn't.

Comment: thanx ,can u provide any link for that, so i can use that.i am new for javascript  .plzzz